# Store contents of a directory in an array, visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am relatively new to visual basic and I am working on a project in which I am going to need to create a "*link*" to individual files that are within a certain directory. This way the user can see all of the files listed out can click on an individual file and run certain things on it. I am sure there are plenty of ways to do this, but if you guys could please give me a few ideas on how I may accomplish this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kyle R.

Comment: VBA or VB.NET? For VB.NET look at Directory.GetFiles() for VBA look into the File system object.

Comment: You know... that may also be a problem. I am not entirely sure, which it is that I am using. I just started with it pretty much and whichever visual studio uses for a visual basic windows forms application by default. (I believe .NET but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio uses VB.Net, and you literally do this:

```
Dim eachFileInMydirectory As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\mydirectory")
```

Now all of the files in mydirectory are stored in **eachFileInMydirectory**, which is an array of string. You will need to add the following line to the very top of your VB file:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't quite expecting it to be this easy. I will definitely see if I can just implement that. 99% of the coding I have done has been command line stuff in C, so this is all is kind of new to me. I have used C++ but never touched visual basic. Thanks for the help!